# Infinite loop inside recursive template function

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, matrix, linear-algebra

I am writing my own library for a university project, containing the template classes: Vector and Matrix. In addition to these template classes, there are also related template functions for vectors and matrices. The professor explicitly told us to define the matrix as a one-dimensional array in which the elements are sorted by column (reasons of efficiency / optimization). The "matrix" template class has 3 template parameters: type of data allowed by the matrix, number of rows, number of columns.

```
template <class T, unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Matrix
```

Having said that, I immediately get to the problem. I'm writing a function that calculates the determinant of any matrix of dimension > 4, using the LaPlace rule for columns (using the first column).
I also wrote a function for two-dimensional matrices (called D2MatrixDet) and a function for three-dimensional matrices (called D3MatrixDet) tested and working:

```
template <class T>
double D2MatrixDet(const Matrix<T, 2, 2>& _m)

template <class T>
double D3MatrixDet(const Matrix<T, 3, 3>& _m)
```

The template function that I have to write has two template parameters: data type of the input matrix, dimension of the matrix (since the determinant is calculated for square matrices, only one dimension is enough). It is a recursive function; the variable "result" is the one that keeps the determinant in memory at each step. Below, the code I wrote.

```
template <class T, unsigned int D>
void DNMatrixDet(Matrix<T, D, D> _m, double result) //LaPlace Rule respect to the first column
{
    const unsigned int new_D = D - 1;
    Matrix<T, new_D, new_D> temp;

    if (D > 3)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _m.row; ++i)
        //Indicate the element to multiply
        {
            for (unsigned int j = _m.row, l = 0; j < _m.row * _m.column && l < pow(new_D, 2); ++j) 
            //Manage the element to be inserted in temp
            {
                bool invalid_row = false;

                for (unsigned int k = 1; k < _m.row && invalid_row == false; ++k) //Slide over row
                {
                    if (j == (i + k * _m.row))
                    {
                        invalid_row = true;
                    }
                }

                if (invalid_row == false)
                {
                    temp.components[l] = _m.components[j];
                    ++l;
                }
            }

            DNMatrixDet(temp, result);
            result += pow((-1), i) * _m.components[i] * result;
        }
    }
    else if (D == 3)
    {
        result += D3MatrixDet(_m);
    }
}
```

In main, I test the function using a 5 x 5 matrix.
When I try to compile, several errors come out, all very similar and that have to do with the size of the matrix which is decreased by one at each step. This is when the initial matrix size is 5 (LA is the name of the library and Test.cpp is the file that contains the main):

```
LA.h: In instantiation of 'void LA::DNMatrixDet(LA::Matrix<T, M, M>, double) [with T = double; 
unsigned int D = 5]':
Test.cpp:437:33:   required from here
LA.h:668:34: error: no matching function for call to 'D3MatrixDet(LA::Matrix<double, 5, 5>&)'
             result += D3MatrixDet(_m);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
In file included from Test.cpp:1:
LA.h:619:12: note: candidate: 'template<class T> double LA::D3MatrixDet(const LA::Matrix<T, 3, 3>&)'
     double D3MatrixDet(const Matrix<T, 3, 3>& _m)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
LA.h:619:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from Test.cpp:1:
LA.h:668:34: note:   template argument '5' does not match '3'
             result += D3MatrixDet(_m);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

This is when the size becomes 4:

```
LA.h: In instantiation of 'void LA::DNMatrixDet(LA::Matrix<T, M, M>, double) [with T = double; 
unsigned int D = 4]':
LA.h:662:28:   required from 'void LA::DNMatrixDet(LA::Matrix<T, M, M>, double) [with T = double; 
unsigned int D = 5]'
Test.cpp:437:33:   required from here
LA.h:668:34: error: no matching function for call to 'D3MatrixDet(LA::Matrix<double, 4, 4>&)'
In file included from Test.cpp:1:
LA.h:619:12: note: candidate: 'template<class T> double LA::D3MatrixDet(const LA::Matrix<T, 3, 3>&)'
     double D3MatrixDet(const Matrix<T, 3, 3>& _m)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
LA.h:619:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from Test.cpp:1:
LA.h:668:34: note:   template argument '4' does not match '3'
             result += D3MatrixDet(_m);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

And so on. It keeps going down until starting over at 4294967295 (which I found to be the upper limit of a 32 bit "unsigned int") and continuing to go down until I reach the maximum number of template instances (= 900).

At each iteration, the compiler always checks the function for calculating the determinant of a 3 x 3, even if that function is only executed when the input matrix is ​​a 3 x 3. So why does it check something that in theory should never to happen?

I double-checked the mathematical logic of what I wrote several times, even with the help of a matrix written on paper and slowly carrying out the first steps. I believe and hope it is right. I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with using templates and recursive function.

I apologize for the very long question, I tried to explain it in the best possible way. I hope I have well explained the problem.

EDIT:
Fixed problem by defining "if constexpr" at the beginning of DNMatrixDet function. The compilation is successful. I just need to fix the algorithm, but this is beyond the scope of the post. Below is the reprex with the changes made:

```
template <class T, unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Matrix
{
    public:

    T components[M * N];
    unsigned int row = M;
    unsigned int column = N;

    Matrix()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M * N; ++i)
        {
            components[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    Matrix(T* _c)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M * N; ++i, ++_c)
        {
            components[i] = *_c;
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix& _m)
    {
        output << _m.row << " x " << _m.column << " matrix:" << std::endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _m.row; ++i)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < _m.column; ++j)
            {
                if (j == _m.column -1)
                {
                    output << _m.components[i + j*_m.row];
                }
                else
                {
                    output << _m.components[i + j*_m.row] << "\t";
                }
            }

            output << std::endl;
        }

        return output;
    }
};
template <class T>
double D3MatrixDet(const Matrix<T, 3, 3>& _m)
{
    double result = _m.components[0] * _m.components[4] * _m.components[8] + 
                    _m.components[3] * _m.components[7] * _m.components[2] +
                    _m.components[6] * _m.components[1] * _m.components[5] -
                    (_m.components[6] * _m.components[4] * _m.components[2] +
                     _m.components[3] * _m.components[1] * _m.components[8] +
                     _m.components[0] * _m.components[7] * _m.components[5]);

    return result;
}
template <class T, unsigned int D>
void DNMatrixDet(Matrix<T, D, D> _m, double result)
{
    Matrix<T, D - 1, D - 1> temp;

    if constexpr (D > 3)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = D, l = 0; j < D * D && l < (D - 1) * (D - 1); ++j)
            {
                bool invalid_row = false;

                for (unsigned int k = 1; k < D && invalid_row == false; ++k)
                {
                    if (j == (i + k * D))
                    {
                        invalid_row = true;
                    }
                }

                if (invalid_row == false)
                {
                    temp.components[l] = _m.components[j];
                    ++l;
                }
            }

            DNMatrixDet(temp, result);
            result += i & 1 ? -1 : 1 * _m.components[i] * result;
        }
    }
    else if (D == 3)
    {
        result += D3MatrixDet(_m);
    }
}

int main()
{
    double m_start[25] = {4, 9, 3, 20, 7, 10, 9, 50, 81, 7, 20, 1, 36, 98, 4, 20, 1, 8, 5, 93, 47, 21, 49, 36, 92};
    Matrix<double, 5, 5> m = Matrix<double, 5, 5> (m_start);
    double m_det = 0;
    DNMatrixDet(m, m_det);
    std::cout << "m is " << m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Det of m is " << m_det << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: i tried to reconstruct your code, but the template alone (with some stuff removed) does not trigger that error (https://godbolt.org/z/q6czGa)

Comment: All the places, where you used `pow()` with integral arguments appear very suspicious to me. `pow(-1, i)` can be written as e.g. `i & 1 ? -1 : 1` or even as `1 - 2 * (i & 1)`. `pow(i, 2)` is better implemented as `i * i`. Please, note that [std::pow()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is provided for floating points only and may introduce weird rounding issues with integral types.

Comment: You need constexpr if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass as an argument `_m` with the type `Matrix<T, 5, 5>`, the trailing else branch contains the code `result += D3MatrixDet(_m);`. The compiler will still try to compile this and notice that it cannot find a matching constructor.

Since we know at compile-time whether to take this branch or not, we can instruct the compiler by using `if constexpr` instead. Since we are within a template, the compiler will no longer check this branch if it is discarded.

So let's change `if (D > 3)` to `if constexpr (D > 3)`.

Comment: Perfect, now compile correctly. I just have to check the algorithm because the result is wrong but in any case the initial problem is solved. Thanks a lot :)